# 不要说话 vs 不说话 (vs 别说话)

Tags: translation, simplified-characters, conversation, spoken

Currently on DuoLingo, and got this sentence:

```
我们看电影的时候请不要说话
```

which means:

```
Please don't talk when we watch movies.
```

My question: is the 要 strictly necessary here?
Google translate actually gives a slightly different translation of

```
我们看电影的时候请不说话
```

Comment: 要 is necessary in the sentence.  要 is necessary when express a demand. E. g.  不要说话！不要随意乱画！etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'要' in '不要' cannot be removed, because '不要' is a compound word that mean 'don't'(auxiliary verb) which is different from '不' (adv: not)

- 不要说话/ 别说话 = Don't talk (demand)
- 不说话 = 'not speak'
- 看电影的时候请(不要)说话 - Please (don't) talk when watching movies (O)
- 看电影的时候请(别)说话 - Please (don't) talk when watching movies (O)
- 看电影的时候请(不)说话 - Please (not) talk when watching movies (X)

*他(不说话) = he (doesn't speak)*

Comment: Thanks, got it 不要 should always be used (or 别)

Comment: However, it is a little confusing, since 要 also means "want". How to say "don't want"?

Comment: Don't want   is 不想

Comment: Or you could also say  "不想要 "

Comment: I agree with @高鵬翔 . `你要不要?` the answer is 不要

Comment: To reply "你想不想 +verb?" , the answer is "想/ 不想"

Comment: To reply "你要不要 +verb/noun" the answer is "要/ 不要"

Comment: To reply "你想不想要 + noun" the answer is "想/ 不想" ;   "要/ 不要" or "我想要/ 我不想要"

Comment: I just focus on "don't want", in my opinion, both 不想 and 不想要 can used , but depend on different situation and habit(Maybe like @TangHo said depend on verb or noun?). Just like if someone ask "Do you want this one?" I would translate it as "你想要這個嗎?" I don't want. "我不(想)要".   And  "Don't want" in google translate have both of it "不想要" and  "不要". So I said "could also say" , there is not only one answer about "don't want"  , have to consider the context. :)

Answer (score 1):

我们看电影的时候请不要说话(√)

我们看电影的时候请别说话(√)

我们看电影的时候请不说话(X)

Comment: Please answer the question whether 要 is needed.